# Insert Auto Increment Column number explicitly from specific Start

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy some data in same table but am willing to add an id column from a specific number sequence. Remember PK (the id column) is auto increment.

```
INSERT INTO `switch_person` (PK, `PTPK`, `EmployeeNamePK`, `SwitchTime`, `Half`, `date`, `Month`, `Year`, `SwitchDate`, `hoursWorked`, `LeadBy`, `Info`, `EmpDaysStatusId`, `TaskPK`, `TaskAssignCompletionId`, `SpendDays`, `LeaveId`, `Comments`)
select [Number will be here with each record increment], `PTPK`, `EmployeeNamePK`, `SwitchTime`, 1, `date`, `Month`, `Year`, `SwitchDate`, `hoursWorked`, `LeadBy`, `Info`, `EmpDaysStatusId`, `TaskPK`, `TaskAssignCompletionId`, `SpendDays`, `LeaveId`, `Comments`
from switch_person
where SwitchDate = '2021-08-17'
and Half = 2
```

Like I want to add PK with 687477 number and next record should be added with 687478 and then 687479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first set the increment to 687477

```
ALTER TABLE switch_person AUTO_INCREMENT=687477;
```

then run your insert, without specifying the pk it will use the autoincrement and increment it for next insert.

```
INSERT INTO `switch_person` (`PTPK`, `EmployeeNamePK`, `SwitchTime`, `Half`, `date`, `Month`, `Year`, `SwitchDate`, `hoursWorked`, `LeadBy`, `Info`, `EmpDaysStatusId`, `TaskPK`, `TaskAssignCompletionId`, `SpendDays`, `LeaveId`, `Comments`)
select `PTPK`, `EmployeeNamePK`, `SwitchTime`, 1, `date`, `Month`, `Year`, `SwitchDate`, `hoursWorked`, `LeadBy`, `Info`, `EmpDaysStatusId`, `TaskPK`, `TaskAssignCompletionId`, `SpendDays`, `LeaveId`, `Comments`
from switch_person
where SwitchDate = '2021-08-17'
and Half = 2
```

Comment: Will this start 687477 or 687478 and after that how to undo it?

Comment: I believe it will start the first insert with 687478. (please try it in test table) why would you undo it ? you cant. mysql needs an autoincrement value anyway. but you can define any other increment after your insert if you want.

Comment: the real question is why managing autoincrement in the first place ? they are automatic